# Не выполняется Handler

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему код выполняется только один раз и всё:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{

@Override
public void run()
{
   updateStatuses upst = new updateStatuses();
   upst.execute();
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Потому что он и должен выполниться один раз, только не сразу, а через секунду. Что бы задача повторялась - пусть она ставит в очередь сама себя в методе `run()` ( ака `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);`

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код обработается лишь 1 раз с задержкой в 1 секунду. Для того, чтобы ваш код запускался каждую 1 сек, добавьте в метод run следующую строку `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);`

**Ниже код, который будет срабатывать раз в секунду:**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        updateStatuses upst = new updateStatuses();
        upst.execute(); 
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
      }
    }, 1000);
```